# How do you deploy a Mongodb database with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, hosting, connection-string, mongodb-atlas

I have a working web app with `MongoDB` database. My app is making fetching/posting info onto the database running on a localhost

```
const db = monk('localhost/datbaseName')   //create/connect to database 'databaseName'
const posts = db.get('posts')   //created a collection named 'posts' in 'databaseName'
```

I recently setup a database `Cluster` on `mongoDB Atlas`. Is there a way to now connect my code to the `Atlas cluster` database, instead of using `localhost/datbaseName`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace
'localhost/datbaseName' with 
mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-1eyxe.mongodb.net/datbasename?retryWrites=true&w=majority

it will connect you with atlas cluster.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about using MongoDB Atlas but a very simple way of deploying your mongo database is to use mlab. You can check them out at https://mlab.com

after logging in to your mlab account click on "create new"
select amazon web services as your cloud provider and also select a free sandbox then hit continue
pick us virginia east and hit continue
give the database a name and then submit your order

once you have completed all that click on the database you just created
click on the users tab and add a database user. over here provide a username and password for the database. you will need this in setting up your mongo connection.

after that is complete you can then copy the mongouri shown and replace the relevant fields with your username and password

Comment: I tried mlab, but It redirects to MongoDB Atlas (they acquired the company i suppose)

Comment: did you get the connection string from your mlab database

Comment: yes, I've tried running it in the mongo shell and it gives me a 'uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: string literal :' error

Answer (score 0):

You are directed to mongodb atlas because mlab has been acquired by mongodb only. I would suggest you to create a cluster on mongodb atlas. You can signup for a free M0 cluster from https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/

Sign up and then click on create cluster.

You can refer to documentation for creating a new cluster here : https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/tutorial/create-new-cluster/index.html

and let me know in case you need more help in setting up the cluster